# Rails Send Email when a Specified Field is Updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an app that is used for tracking in house devices. Once a device has been through the system it ships, so I am updating the 'Ticket'. I've been through a lot of contact form tutorials but they don't really help because they are all based on either gems or create methods.

The code below mostly works but with two glaring problems: The @ticket.tracking is not passing in tracking to appear in the email and it is trying to find the linked template when it should just perform the action then redirect back to the edit page.

Form:

```
<%= form_for(@ticket, url: send_tracking_mail_path(@ticket)) do |tickettracking| %>
  <%= tickettracking.text_field :tracking %>
  <%= tickettracking.submit 'Submit Tracking', class: "btn btn-primary btn-mini", style: "float: right;" %>
<% end %>
```

Ticket Controller:

```
def send_tracking_mail
 @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
 TrackingMailer.tracking(@ticket).deliver_now
 flash[:notice] = "Ticket tracking has been sent."
end
```

Tracking Mailer:

```
class TrackingMailer < ApplicationMailer
 def tracking(ticket)
  @ticket = ticket
  mail(to: @ticket.customer.email, subject: "Tracking for #{ticket.name}")
 end
end
```

The route:

```
patch 'send_tracking_mail.:id', to: 'tickets#send_tracking_mail', as: :send_tracking_mail
```

The email sends but renders nothing for <%= @ticket.tracking %>

```
Your Device Has Been Shipped with tracking <%= @ticket.tracking %>
```

Edit:
I was missing a couple of lines in the email method

```
def send_tracking_mail
 @ticket = Ticket.find(params[:id])
 @ticket.update(ticket_params)
 TrackingMailer.tracking(@ticket).deliver_now
 redirect_to edit_ticket_path(@ticket)
end
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean by _is not passing in time to appear in the email_. As for the redirect, that's because you've not added a redirect in the action.

Comment: My mistake, that was supposed to be tracking. Thanks for the redirect tip.

Comment: So it's not passing in the ticket to the mailer?

Comment: Ticket is passing, but I just noticed that tracking isn't committing to the database either. By directing the form_for to a different url will it not update anymore?

Comment: You don't update the ticket's attributes or save them